# Django and loading PHP session_start() in templates

Tags: php, python, django

I'm working with Django and an existing site that uses regular php/mysql for user accounts and authentication. To allow the django templates to interpret any php within them, I'm using 'django_php' (https://github.com/mvasilkov/django-php).  Everything works to the point where the php login will successfully run on the django template, *however* placing sesion_start() at the top of the page causes it to throw a "headers already sent" error.  Does anyone know how I could go about continuing the session within the template?

The code at the top of the index.html template:

```
{% load php %}
{% php session_start(); %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
```

Note: The django app itself does not use the user information, so I would prefer to not go the route of doing all auth (or any at all) in django.

Comment: It is usually bad idea to use sessions in templates (everywhere), as it breaks the MVC pattern. Pass the variables from session to View by your Controller.

Comment: django probably has its own headers. if your only using php templates why do you need php session? your session should be handled by django

Comment: @DevZer0 the Django app only resides in a sub-directory of the full website.  I'd just like it to be seamless for the visitor (if they log in at the homepage, and then navigate to the django subfolder, I'd like it to still show them as logged in, give them the menu for a logged in user).  I'm trying to keep the django footprint small enoguh where it doesn't need to handle to sesion.

Comment: It looks like the entire django-php library is a joke and not supposed to be used in real applications... This looks like an absolutely horrible hack with most likely hideously poor performance to boot :P

Comment: @JaniHartikainen not surprising.  Do you think an appropriate template loaded for PHP exists?

Comment: @user636127 if you need access to PHP's sessions from non-PHP code, I would suggest looking into storing the sessions in a database. This way you can easily load the PHPSESSID cookie in your django app and look up the necessary data from the DB.